# Bug while checking for symbols inside of a string?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I'm creating a small calculator script and I've got stumbled on a strange bug. Everything seems to work but not when I input anything starting with `(`. When I do that `if` gives false and the code inside of `else` executes. I've tried a lot of ways rewriting how should `"$input" =~ [-,+,*,/,\(,\)]` look like but nothing worked. Do you have any idea why that's happening and how to solve this bug?

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Input: " input
if [[ ! "$input" =~ ^[A-Za-z_]+$ && "$input" =~ ^[0-9] && "$input" =~ [-,+,*,/,\(,\)] ]]; then
 (echo $input = $(($input))) 2>- || echo "Please, do not input ..."
else
 echo "Please, do not input letters or other special symbols and type in only expressions."
fi
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the back slashes I'm front of the parentheses?  You shouldn't need those, I think, in a `[]` character match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to make sure your input consists of just certain characters, use this much simpler regex:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -r -p "Input: " input

if [[ $input =~ ^[0-9+*/()-]*$ ]]; then
   (echo "$input = $((input))") 2> /dev/null || echo "Please, do not input ..."
else
   echo "Please, do not input letters or other special symbols and type in only expressions."
fi
```

Answer (score 4):

1. > ...when I input anything starting with `(`. When I do that if gives false

   That is because the second test requires that expressions start with a number: when an expression starts with `(`, the test `"$input" =~ ^[0-9]` fails.
2. `[-,+,*,/,\(,\)]` can be simplified to `[-,+*/()]`.  This is because (a) the parens do not need to be escaped inside `[...]`, and (b) there is no reason to specify `,` five times within a square bracket expression, `[...]`.  If you want the regex to match a comma, listing it once is sufficient.   If you don't want it to match a comma, don't put the comma inside `[...]`.

Comment: Wrt point #2: there is no separator between characters in a character class. (Maybe there should not be a `,` at all if the intent was only to separate the other letters.. a question to toss back at the OP.)

Comment: @user2864740 Very good.  I edited the answer to make it more clear on that point.

Comment: Big thanks for the answer, I'll take it into account.